# Moved my drupal 7 site to a new server, can't log in

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, phpmyadmin

I have a very strange problem since I moved my drupal site to a new server.

**here's the problem description:**

When i try to log in the login page (http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=user) just reloads and I can't see my admin panel. If i try to acces an admin page manually i get an access denied message which indicates the login failed. If i type in an incorrect login name or password i get the same behaviour. When trying to request a new password the page just reloads (as above) and i get no email.

**This is how i moved the site:**

I copied and moved the files, exported and imported the database with phpmyadmin and edited the sessions.php by changeing the base_url and editing the db information.

The site works fine, I can look att all the pages but I just can't log in!

**Here's what I've tried:**

Deleted the drupal folder and the database and tried again.

Used different methods to change admin password (drush, MD5, in the users table in phpmyadmin).

Changed the permissions of the whole drupal folder to 777.

Commented away the cookie_domain in the settings.php file.

Added       *drupal_page_footer();
                 $GLOBALS['tempUser'] = $user;*        to my index.php file.

Emptied all the tables in the database that starts with cache.

Tried different web browsers and clearing cache.

**Here is some more information:**

The two servers have the same version of php (5.2.3).

I can log in to the old page with no problem.

The user table in the db looks fine except the acces and login timestamps are old (from before I moved the server).

The watchdog table contain no entries from failed logins but when I try to access http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin it generates an entry (access denied) but the timestamp is wrong by 1 hour.

The server time is fine.

SpaceBeers asked for the watchdog table, here it is:

```
===Database orma

== Table structure for table watchdog

|------
|Field|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**wid**//|int(11)|No|
|uid|int(11)|No|0
|type|varchar(64)|No|
|message|longtext|No|
|variables|longblob|No|
|severity|tinyint(3) |No|0
|link|varchar(255)|Yes|
|location|text|No|
|referer|text|Yes|NULL
|hostname|varchar(128)|No|
|timestamp|int(11)|No|0
== Dumping data for table watchdog

|3344|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/| |83.233.148.7|1331513088
|3345|0|access denied|user/1|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=user/1| |83.233.148.7|1331515605
|3346|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/| |83.233.148.35|1331548875
|3347|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/| |129.16.208.199|1332154845
|3348|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/| |83.233.148.63|1332193286
|3349|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |83.233.148.63|1332195196
|3350|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |83.233.148.63|1332195841
|3351|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |83.233.148.63|1332198728
|3352|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |83.233.148.63|1332200257
|3353|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |83.233.148.63|1332200428
|3354|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |83.233.148.63|1332200431
|3355|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=user| |83.233.148.35|1332322440
|3356|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |76.123.53.220|1332336792
|3357|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |76.123.53.220|1332336792
|3358|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |76.123.53.220|1332336815
|3359|0|access denied|admin|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=admin| |76.123.53.220|1332337311
|3360|0|page not found|register|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=register| |76.123.53.220|1332337314
|3361|0|access denied|user/register|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=user/register| |76.123.53.220|1332337322
|3362|0|access denied|user/register|N;|4| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/?q=user/register| |76.123.53.220|1332337354
|3363|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/| |83.248.70.120|1332353203
|3364|0|cron|Cron run completed.|a:0:{}|5| |http://129.16.208.27/drupal/| |130.235.234.145|1332418164
== Table structure for table watchdog

|------
|Field|Type|Null|Default
|------
|//**wid**//|int(11)|No|
|uid|int(11)|No|0
|type|varchar(64)|No|
|message|longtext|No|
|variables|longblob|No|
|severity|tinyint(3) |No|0
|link|varchar(255)|Yes|
|location|text|No|
|referer|text|Yes|NULL
|hostname|varchar(128)|No|
|timestamp|int(11)|No|0
```

I have spent many hours checking for solutions without success, please help me!

Comment: Can you create a temporary test user so we can troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have fixed this before, something to do with updating the BLOB in the user table. Will hunt down details for you.

Comment: @jsheffers : That sounds very interesting. I will create a test user as soon as I get home tonight. To create a user you just create a new entry in the users table right?

Comment: @SpaceBeers : Finally someone who have experienced the same problem! I look forward to hear the details.

Comment: Can you access the database watchdog table?

Comment: Does that tell you anything useful?

Comment: @SpaceBeers : Nothing I am really capable of interpreting other than that you're probably from virginia:P. There are no entries from failed logins, but there are entries from "access denied" events. The entries from the access denied events are one hour old. If I for example try to access the admin pages at 12:00, the entry will come up in the watchdog table immediately but the timestamp will say that the event is one hour old. Don't know if that means anything but that's the only strange thing I can find. I have posted the watchdog table in the question if you want to take a closer look!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked your sites `settings.php` file?

Make sure it matches your current details AND that the leading . is in place in the line below:

```
$cookie_domain = '.mydomain.co.uk';
```

Comment: Hmm, you might have found something there. I had that line commented out like: # $cookie_domain = '129.16.208.27'; So I changed to just $cookie_domain = '.129.16.208.27'; and $cookie_domain = '.129.16.208.27/drupal'; And after a little while the whole page stopped working. Now it is just a white screen and when I commented away the cookie_domain again it didn't fix it... What does that mean?

Comment: If you set it back to how it was can you get the site back?

Comment: no I can't! (but don't worry I have the site safe and running somewhere else). This is very strange.I might have to upload a fresh version of the server and database since I might have messed something up while trying to fix this problem

Comment: ok it seems quite localised so I'd say run a clean install on your server and then just copy your theme and DB over once that's working.

Comment: I installed a fresh drupal site on the server and then gradually moved the old site over, now it works!

Answer (score 18):

Check your server has rewrite_module enabled

I had the same problem with apache2 on ubuntu server

I ran

> sudo a2enmod rewrite

then

> sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

and away it went :)

Comment: Didn't try this, maybe someone else with the same problem can give it a try?!

Comment: You are awesome! This was my problem after migrating to a fresh new ubuntu server. The apache installation guide did not have this for rewrite! Been struggling with this for hours now and couldnt login to my site.

Comment: recently had this same problem - this answer is gold

Comment: Wow... its resolved at atlast... I was searching for this for couple of days and finally the issue is resolved. That's Man! you are awesome ! :-)

Comment: Thank you! Wasted two and half hours trying to get a local copy of the site working! Was about to throw my machine out the window. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Did you change database infos in /sites/mysite/settings.php to match the new database?

Try to clear drupal cache. To do so, empty every table starting by cache.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Alytrem. Yes I have done both of these things, I will add the information to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I fixed it!

I installed a fresh drupal site on the server and made sure it worked properly. Then I gradually moved the old site over piece by piece while checking after every piece if I could still log in. The site looked pretty ugly in the middle of this process but as soon as I had everything I needed from the old site it looked good again.

This is what pieces from the old site I moved:

database
drupal/themes folder
drupal/sites/default/files folder
drupal/sites/all folder
drupal/modules folder

And it works like a charm! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We spent hours on this and exhausted every possible option, even rackspace's "fanatical support" couldn't fix it. I paid an engineer in the end and he found:

```
# yum list installed | grep suhosin
php54-suhosin.x86_64               0.9.34-20120520.1.ius.el6          @ius      
# yum remove php54-suhosin.x86_64
```

fixed the problem.